# Laravel Many To Many Polymorphic Relation : Get child with higher priority with each record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.5

In my **Laravel 5.5** application, `many to many polymorphic relation` is used for pointing the relation between `destinations` and `photos`. There is a `priority` column in the pivot table for storing the precedence of each relation.

What I need is, access all `destination` records with one related `photo` of higher **priority**.

I was able to access all destination with all related photos. But when I try to narrow the selection of related item to 'one' with higher priority it doesn't work.

Migration for `destinations` table :

```php
Schema::create('destinations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 100)->unique();
    $table->string('tag_line', 200);
});
```

Migration for `photos` table :

```php
Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('image_name', 100)->unique();
});
```

Migration for `publishables` table :

```php
Schema::create('publishables', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('photo_id');
    // publishable_id and publishable_type
    $table->morphs('publishable');
    $table->tinyInteger('priority');
});
```

**Destination** Model :

```php
class Destination extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the images for the destination.
     */
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Photo', 'publishable')->as('destinationPhotoDetail')->withPivot('priority');
    }
}
```

**Photo** Model :

```php
class Photo extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the destinations that are assigned this photo.
     */
    public function destinations()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Destination', 'publishable');
    }
}
```

**Methods which I have tried** :

```php
$destinations = Destination::with(['photos']);
```

**Output** : It gives all related `photos`

```php
$destinations = Destination::with(['photos' => function ($query) {
                    $query->orderBy('priority', 'desc')->first();
                }]);
```

**Output** : It gives only one photo with higher priority for only one destination.

`publishables` **table data**:

[image]

From this db table data,

Photo where id = 1 should be get with Destination where id = 1[only one with priority 1]

Photo where id = 2 should be get with Destination where id = 2[record with priority 2]

Comment: Why do you only want to get one photo per destination? To increase the query performance?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The query is used for a preview. Only one photo is required for this.

Comment: There's no simple way to limit eager loading like this. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571322/4848587

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir As per your comment, a hack is used for now.  **reversed my priority style**. Now I check for priority = 1`.Destination::with(['photos' => function ($query) {$query->where('priority', 1);}]);`.